# What does pods_<project-name>.framework do?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this file in my framework turned red and it does not exist in the location shown in xcode.

Comment: Is that your private pod framework?

Comment: Add pod code / error log or screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer... A clue maybe. In my projects the `Pods_<project name>.framework` group folder in Xcode contains a reference to a header file `Pods-<project name>-umbrella.h`. When I `Show in Finder`, the header file is located in my debug folder:

[image: framework contained in build outputs]

So this appears to be a build artifact related to the Pods framework... Perhaps so you can export the project to CocoaPods? Doesn't seem required when I delete it from the Xcode project.